# How does socket select() work?

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

As described in network programming books, select() monitors a set of file descriptors for reading. For example, here is part of code:

```
select(numfds, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Here `numfds` is maximum number of socket in read_fds + 1. Does it mean, that every "monitor" cycle `select()` watchs through all file descriptors of the process from 0 to numfds? I mean, if I have only two file descriptors to monitor(0 and 26), does select watch all descriptors from 0 to 26?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every monitor cycle means, whenever the operating system gets around to it essentially, it may choose to periodically check the descriptors or handle it via event or interrupts. When data is received on a socket file descriptor the descriptor file gets populated with data and the process that was waiting on it is informed. This doesn't always happen immediately as the process isn't woken immediately it is simply put back on the ready to run queue (since it was blocked by the select call). If the select call happens to fail (no data received in timeout) then a timer fires and puts the process back on the run queue.

Yes fd's in the `FD_SET` 0-26 are checked or monitored. This is just to put an upper bound on the search for file descriptors. IIRC this is because an `fd_set` type is implemented as a bitset internally since it is easier to specify indexes as this can save space. I may be wrong in the previous statement as I haven't visited that code in glibc in a while.

Answer (score 9):

`select` chooses which fds to watch based on the fd sets you pass in (`readfds`, `writefds`, `exceptfds`). The sets are typically implemented as bit vectors, so `select` will scan over the vector to see what fds are selected. As an optimization, you pass in the number of fds to scan up to so that `select` doesn't have to look at all fds up to `FD_SETSIZE` (which might not even be the same across compilation units).

`select` is a fairly expensive call because of the scanning and the necessity of resetting the sets after every call to `select`. On many platforms, `select` is just implemented on top of the `poll` system call, which offers a more efficient interface for waiting on file descriptors.

Comment: Yes, but does it scans all sockets from 0 to numfds?

Comment: Why is it the caller's responsibility to add one?

Comment: @dreamlax same reason c-strings are terminated in `\0` because someone said so and it's been like that ever since.

Comment: @TuralGurbanov: Yes, it will scan everything from `0` to `numfds`. Use `poll` if you want to avoid that (bonus: `poll` doesn't modify the input array, so you don't have to keep re-adding the fds each loop).

Comment: Because we're begining our count from 0. So if our highest socket fd equal to 26, this means that we should watch descriptors from 0 to 26 and this equals to `highest_socket + 1`